# Removing scope for jawbone user

Tags: jawbone

My application has requested moves and sleeps scope for a particular user. Now he wants to remove the sleep scope.

Is there an api to do it? or do I need to re-authorize the user again requesting only one scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to re-authorize the user with the updated scope because the user must confirm the permission change.

Send the user down the same [authentication flow](https://jawbone.com/up/developer/authentication), and save the new token.